# used barcode scanner function keyup executed twice

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

i have assigned each student a barcode in their IDs. and im using barcode scanner to scan their IDs to check their attendance. im using a keyup function but everytime i scanned the barcode in their ID the keyup function executed twice.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">


       function loaddelegates($barcode)
         {
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
              if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
               document.getElementById("getdel").innerHTML = this.responseText;
               $("#barcode").focus();
              }
            };
            xhttp.open("GET", "mealclient/" + $barcode, true);
            xhttp.send();

          }

$(function() {
           $('#barcode').attr('maxlength','13');
        $(document).on('keyup','#barcode',function(e) {
           e.preventDefault();
            if ($(this).val().length >= 13) {
                loaddelegates($(this).val());
                return false;
            }
        });
      });
```

```
  <div class="site-wrapper-inner">

    <div class="cover-container">

      <div class="masthead clearfix">
        <div class="inner">
          <h3 class="masthead-brand">PITYLC</h3>
          <nav>
            <ul class="nav masthead-nav">
            @foreach($meals as $meal)
              <li class="active"><a href="#">{{$meal->date}}</a></li>
            @endforeach
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
      <img src="/img/COVER.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">

      <div class="inner cover" id = "getdel">
      @foreach($meals as $meal)
        <h1 class="cover-heading" style = "font-weight: Bold">{{strtoupper($meal->meal)}}</h1>
      @endforeach
         <div class="form-group">
            <label style = "color: #e36c1d">BARCODE</label>
            <input class="form-control" style="font-size:30px; color: #e36c1d"  id = "barcode" autofocus>
        </div>
         <div class="form-group">
            <label style = "color: #e36c1d">NAME</label>
            <input class="form-control" style="font-size:30px; color: #e36c1d" >
        </div>
         <div class="form-group" >
            <label style = "color: #e36c1d">ORGANIZATION</label>
            <input class="form-control" style="font-size:30px; color: #e36c1d" >
        </div>
         <div class="form-group">
            <label style = "color: #e36c1d">POSITION</label>
            <input class="form-control" style="font-size:30px; color: #e36c1d">
        </div>
         <div class="form-group">
            <label style = "color: #e36c1d">SCHOOL</label>
            <input class="form-control" style="font-size:30px; color: #e36c1d">
        </div>


      </div>



    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could imagine that the barcode reader is somehow simulating a key press, as you listen for keyup. Probably it simulates two keys - e.g. `Ctrl + V` would call your function twice.

To debug this issue I would recommend to add

```
var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
console.log(code);
```

at the very top of your keyup listener. Check the console output. So if the reader really simulates two keys at once you could certainly ignore one of both.

EDIT: As the OP wrote, 13 is shown up in the console additionally to another key code.
13 is the ASCII code for CR (carriage return).

So to ignore this key write:

```
$(document).on('keyup','#barcode',function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
      if (code != 13 && $(this).val().length >= 13) {
          loaddelegates($(this).val());
      }
});
```

Comment: its key 54.. what key is that

Comment: key code 54 is the key 6. Was this the last number of your scanned barcode? It's just called once? Try it with several different barcodes and watch out for two keys at once

Comment: Probably 13 is the issue, which I had already in mind before.
It's the ASCII character CR (carriage return)
http://www.asciitable.com/

try to ignore this one somehow like if(code != 13) ...

Comment: whats the code for me to ignore that key? sorry im knew in developing webs

Comment: ok, I'll update my answer with the code. So 13 is always shown now, when you scan a new one?

Comment: yes 13 is shown as last key code even when i scan new barcode

Comment: thank you ! finally after how many hours of searching for solution . u save my day :D

Comment: I'm glad I could help :)